# How to execute a bash script without calling its path?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, terminal

I have the file `script.sh` in `my-directory` folder.
How to run this script with the command `script' from the terminal with no regards to the location I am in the terminal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do so by exporting the path where your script in the `PATH` environment variable, so that you don't ever have to worry about what your actual script's location is, i.e. if your script is present under say `/path/to/dir`, do

```
export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/dir
```

so that your script's path gets appended to an already existing set if paths under `PATH`, also remember if you run the above from the command-line, it is not permanent and gets lost soon after the session is terminated. To make it permanent add the same line in `.bashrc` (or) `.bash_profile`, depending upon your environment.

Or creating a symbolic link from `/usr/bin` that is what you intent to do you can do something like `ln -s /full/path/to/myscript.sh /usr/bin/myscript` and then run as just `myscript` directly from command line. You can also confirm if is properly added by checking the script's location by `which` command,

```
 $ which myscript
/usr/bin/myscript
```

Comment: is not there a folder something like `/usr/bin' or something like that where I can create a symlink?

Comment: `/usr/bin` is not meant for adding custom user scripts, but only for shell utilities, however this method does not harm in any way and can be recommended for adding pathless execution of script.

Comment: @Cristian: Or if that is what you intent to do you can do something like `ln -s script.sh /usr/bin/script` and then run as just `script` from command line

Comment: If you're removing the extension, you should use shebang to specify which interpreter it should use. More info here: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix))

Comment: @GowthamG: Fair point, depends on which shell the author wants the script to run under, `sh` or `bash` shell.

Comment: @Inian Non only the shell, but also the interpreter like `#!/usr/bin/env python` or `#!/usr/bin/env ruby`. But, in this context, yeah you're right.

Answer (score 1):

Say your directory is `/home/Cristian/my-directory` then you can make that part of PATH environment variable like `export PATH=$PATH:/home/Cristian/my-directory` and then you will be able to call it by typing `script.sh` and not `script`. If you want it to be called as `script` then you should name it `script` and rename the extension.

The export command will make the directory in question part of PATH temporarily. To make it permanent you may want it to part of `.bashrc` or other shell `rc` file if you are in other shells.